# Where can I find SQL server developer edition (2005 or 2008)

Tags: sql-server, download

As far as I know, the developer edition of SQL Server is available to everyone. I cannot seem to locate the download anywhere though! I have a technet plus, but even there I don't see the developer edition. I need the developer edition for the enterprise-only features, or I'd use SQL Server Express.

Update 1. I am NOTlooking for SQL express.

Update 2. I have tried Google (extensively)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no special licencing (like Academic) to buy *Developer* edition. The only difference is that the EULA licence included states you cannot use the software for production environments (only for testing/development).

Want to buy it?

[Microsoft Store](http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/SQL-Server-2008-Developer-Edition/product/C5EA00C9?WT.mc_id=productinfocenter) ($49.95, same price as Amazon used to sell 2005 Developer for)

Edit: Just to clarify, Developer Edition is *not* a free product. Some of the MSDN subscriptions (which cost far more then $49.95) include it as a perk, but it is still a shrink wrapped retail product as far as Microsoft is concerned.

Comment: Thanks! I seem to remember the 2000 version of the developer edition was free, but I'll gladly pay the $49.95. The search has cost me way more in time already :)

Comment: Interesting! I had no idea you could get it outside of an MSDN subscription. Good to know :)

Comment: It has almost certainly been handed out for free at any number of Microsoft sponsored events, but at least *I* had to pay for the shrink wrapped version of SQL Server Developer Edition 2000 from Amazon (came with the system tables fold out poster and 2 extra CDs with the enhanced reporting tools and such). Now there was MSDE 2000, which was free, but it was a kind of grandfather to SQL Express.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:  https://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/developer.aspx

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

You definitely get developer edition via microsoft's MSDNAA academic program.

Developer edition is essentially the enterprise edition with license restrictions.

Use enterprise edition then.

If you have no license for enterprise edition, you will anyway not be able to use in production whatever you come up with in developer edition.

If you don't care about licenses, you can probably download it from anywhere you find. But then google is a better place to ask than SO community.

EDIT: You cannot legally get either developer of enterprise edition for free. If your customer does not give you a license, and if you don't buy one yourself, you have no legal options to perform this job.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to use the developer edition. The enterprise license is supplied by the customer(s)

Comment: Mastermind, your comment "use enterprise edition then" seems to imply that the developer edition has no purpose. I'd strongly disagree with that. If you have an environment with a valid enterprise license for production, then using the Developer edition in the development environment is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Then ask your customer for the DVD. If he needs the work to get done, he could provide you with software. For an employee the employer provides all working tools. Of course, if you are self-employed, it may be necessary that you buy both VS and SQL for your own money.

Comment: @Mastermind, that would be violating their license for enterprise (unless, of course, they have one available, but given the price I'm fairly certain that nobody has "extra" licenses for Enterprise lying around...).

Comment: @Adam, I'm sure you're right. I was just trying to point out that without a valid production license the developer edition is just a toy to play with. If neither you nor your customer have the licence, you software will end up in sandbox and never go productive. Correct me please, if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @mastermind. I am self employed. The customer has the license. He will (and should) not give it to me.

Comment: Then you may not perform your task.

Comment: @Mastermind, Again, doesn't seem helpful. The man is asking HOW to get it. The correct answer is not "you can't use it" or something assenine like that, it's to tell him that it's part of an MSDN subscription (which it is).

Comment: You're right I suppose. I should have chosen the other words. The only option for "getting it" I had was to go out and buy it. But that seemed obvious enough to mention it.

Comment: Clearly he didn't know where or how (evidently I didn't, either).

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't really programming related, I'll answer anyway.

The developer edition is not, in fact, available to everyone. To the best of my knowledge, the only way to obtain it is via an MSDN subscription (not TechNet, I don't think; sorry!) that includes server software (so something above the "Operating Systems" subscription level).

I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and assume that your need for the enterprise only features is for a development environment and that the deployment environment has a valid license for the enterprise edition. If that's the case, then you'll have to obtain an MSDN subscription.

Out of curiousity, what "enterprise only" features are you planning on using? In my experience, a fairly small percentage of developers actually need anything above the functionality offered in the Standard edition.

Comment: Thanks (for the benefit) I need to tinker with the both the mirror (high-performance) and the table partitioning functions.

Comment: Ah, then that would explain it! Unfortunately it still looks like you're going to have to get yourself an MSDN subscription in order to get ahold of Developer edition.